# ng-hide to hide data when the submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to hide the date for:{{...}} data which is getting the date when the user submits their own date. I have tried using class="check-element animate-hide" ng-hide="checked" example from angularjs page. But it does not seem to work with the type="submit" for me.
how else can I implement this?
HTML:

```
    <center>
      <button ng-hide="checked" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Fetch</button>
    </center>
 </div>
    </form>
       <span ng-controller="MAUsCtrl" style="text-align: center"></span>
       <!-- I want to hide the below data when submit is pressed--> 
       <span type="date" ng-model="date" style="text-align: center">
          <h4> Data for:{{ date | date: 'MM/yyyy' }}</h4>
       </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
        <center>
            <button ng-click="visible = false" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Fetch</button>
        </center>
    </div>
</form> 
<span ng-controller="MAUsCtrl" style="text-align: center"></span>
<!-- I want to hide the below data when submit is pressed--> 
<span ng-show="visible" type="date" ng-model="date" style="text-align: center"><h4> Data for:{{ date | date: 'MM/yyyy' }}</h4></span>
```

And in your controller set the default value of visible to true

```
$scope.visible = true;
```

Comment: Okay That has worked, and what If I wanted to display the chosen date for the user after the pressed fetch would I do the same

Comment: Yes you could set the visible variable back to true !

Comment: But It is not the same data I want to display, it is a different data. so I want other data to display which is in another span tag when fetch is pressed

Comment: I added ng-hide="visible" in the other span, Thanks for your help